Проблема с авторизацией в Django после смены модели
В общем, у меня есть model user'ов и проблема раньше была такая: когда пользователь регистрировался, то данные сохранялись в админке джанго не в его стандартной модели Users (идет по умолчанию), а в моей созданной модели которую я отобразил через admin.py. По этому выполнить логин не получалось, так как вьюха отвечающая за логин брала данные ИЗ МОДЕЛИ USERS (В DJANGO ПО УМОЛЧАНИЮ) когда сами данные зарегистрированных пользователей находились в моей модели, по этому залогинеться не получалось.
Как я решил часть проблемы: я сделал так что бы модель пользователей в django по умолчанию была моделью которую я сделал. И пользователи по прежнему там отображались после регистрации, с этим все нормально. Но ЛОГИН я так же не могу выполнить по какой-то неведомой причине, помогите пожалуйста решить мою проблему, буду очень благодарен и признателен если поможете.
settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    В коде, UserManager не используется напрямую, но он указан в классе User как objects.
    Это означает, что UserManager используется для управления объектами класса User в Django.
    Он тут не ипользуется на прямую, но отвечает за удаление, добовление объектов класса User
    """
    # Указание что этот менджер должен быть использован в миграциях джанго
    use_in_migrations = True

    # Создание пользователя и вывод исключения в терминал
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('У пользователя должен быть email')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)  # Нормализует данные, переводит в нижний регистор, удаляет пробелы и т.д
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)  # Ссылка на модель, передача email и других полей (extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)  # Устонавливает пароль
        user.save(using=self._db)  # Сохроняет пользователя в бд
        return user

    # Создание супер пользователя
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Authorized user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Authorized users'

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from users.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from users.forms import UserRegistrationForm, UserLoginForm


def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)  # Не сохраняется в бд
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            user.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:login_user'))
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': 'Register in website'
    }
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)


def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid")
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                print(f"User logged in: {username}")
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myblog:index'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': form})


def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myblog:index'))

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from users.views import register_user, login_user, logout_user

app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', register_user, name='register_user'),
    path('login/', login_user, name='login_user'),
    path('logout/', logout_user, name='logout_user'),
]

login.html
{% extends 'users/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
<title>Login</title>
{% block content %}
    {% include 'myblog/complex/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class="container">
        <form action="{% url 'users:login_user' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if form.errors %}
                <ul>
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if field.errors %}
                            <li>{{ field.label }}: {{ field.errors|join:", " }}</li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- Rest of your form -->
            <div class="login">
                    <div class="login__title">Login for <br>this website</div>
                    <div class="login__subtitle">If you already have an account, simply log in by entering your details.</div>
                    <div class="login__fields">
                        <div class="login__fields__username">
                            {{ form.username }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="login__fields__password">
                            {{ form.password }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login__buttons">
                        <button class="login__btn" type="submit">Login in account</button>
                        <p class="linktext">You don't have account? <a href="{% url 'users:register_user' %}" class="linktext">Register</a></p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}


не знаю, может можно как-то во вью логина (views.py) сделать так что бы ОНА БРАЛА ДАННЫЕ именно из модели которую Я СОЗДАЛ? такое возможно в теории как-то сделать? просто других вариантов у меня нету
